# How can I find envelop of FFT spectrum?

Tags: python, fft, spectrum, envelope

Here is my FFT result.
[image: Whole spectrum]
Whole spectrum graph

[image]
Zoom In graph

There are so many noisy points, and I want to get a simple envelop line of the result.

I have used the find_peaks function, but it was not working well.
`peaks2, _ = find_peaks(Xk1_shift, prominence= 10**5)`

Could you give me some advise?

Comment: Probably you have to go through each data point and check for local maxima. If that is too noisy, then you'll have to do some smoothing or low pass filtering.

Comment: I tried let new spectrum value array y[n], original spectrum array x[n], and {ay[n-1] + bx[n}]/(a+b) . and tuning coefficient a,b. But it is not working well.

Comment: There are some good pointers here
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/734/calculating-a-spectral-envelope